# How to Show Captcha images for repeated requests

Tags: asp.net, security, captcha, denial-of-service

In my project, to avoid spammers and other Security issues, I have to show Captcha Image for repeated requests from same IP Address.
That is, If I get multiple requests from same IP Address, then my Captcha should be shown to check the user..

So, my task, If I get 10 requests within 5 seconds from same IP, then Captcha should be enabled to that IP address...

Any Suggestion Will be highly appreciated..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Split the task into steps, and then try to think around each step.

> If I get 10 requests within 5 seconds from same IP,

1) So you need to identify that you're under attack. E.g. see 
[Block DoS attacks easily in ASP.NET](http://madskristensen.net/post/block-dos-attacks-easily-in-aspnet)

> then
>   Captcha should be enabled to that IP address...

2) So you need to show a captcha. E.g. [Using a CAPTCHA to Prevent Bots from Using Your ASP.NET Web Razor) Site](http://www.asp.net/web-pages/tutorials/security/using-a-catpcha-to-prevent-automated-programs-%28bots%29-from-using-your-aspnet-web-site)

3) Then probably you would need to save "validated" IP into a "white" list.